# using java to get currernt DateTime in XSLT 1.0

Tags: java, datetime, xslt-1.0

As XSLT 1.0 has no way of retrieving the current date-time, I searched for a solution and found that it can be done using java.

I want to set a variable, so have this snippet

```
<xsl:variable name="vCurrDate">
  <xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'), java:java.util.Date.new())" />
</xsl:variable>
```

However I'm obviously not using the correct namespace, does anyone know what it should be? Currently I have

```
xmlns:java="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
```

Thanks

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Not entirely sure - how would I find that out?

Comment: How are you invoking the transformation?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that in the first place.  It's custom XSLT for a Biztalk 2013 map

Comment: I doubt it supports Java extensions at all.

Comment: thanks for your time anyway. I've binned that approach and will just pass the xml message into a C# helper class.  i was just curious to see if I could do it within the map.